# Dlib "Error deserializing object of type short"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, face-recognition, dlib

I am getting error on `pose_predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_model)` on dlib python.

```
RuntimeError: Error deserializing object of type short
   while deserializing a floating point number.
   while deserializing a dlib::matrix
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
```

Comment: this is very common error. you should download shape predictor model file and unpack it from archive. its also possible that file is corrupted while downloading, its size should be (unpacked) 99693937 bytes, sha1 = c7b0e0780a4fda180f75aadf654838c1866ee5fb

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy i'll try to download model again , and will verify with given sha1.

Comment: Yeah @Evgeniy it worked <3 can u write this comment as answer ? so that i can accept the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I met the same issue and tried re-downloading the file, then it's OK now.

I downloaded from 
https://github.com/JeffTrain/selfie/blob/master/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

Answer (score 4):

Download using command

```
wget -nd https://github.com/JeffTrain/selfie/raw/master/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

when downloading from github download raw file instead of blob.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone. I was using google colab and redownloading and reuploading did not work for me.
So I cloned a git repo which had the shape predictor and used it's path

This is what I did

```
!git clone https://github.com/nicolasmetallo/eameo-faceswap-generator

cd eameo-faceswap-generator
```

Then change your shape predictor's path to

```
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
```

Then run your code