# dlib.shape_predictor: deserializing object of type int

Tags: python, dlib

```
import dlib
import cv2
import numpy as np
predictor_path =r'C:\Users\susi\Downloads\surveillens_ai\app\icudtl.dat'
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\susi\Desktop\Industry 4.0\Untitled-1.py", line 5, in <module>
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
RuntimeError: Error deserializing object of type int
```

Comment: Have you tried with any other predictor file ?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981231/dlib-error-deserializing-object-of-type-short

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Likely your `icudtl.dat` file is corrupted; download it again. If possible, verify its checksum matches the provided value from the source.